# float:right in the correct order it appears in HTML code

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a container div and two child divs both with the `float: right` property.

My code looks like:

```
<div class="container">               .container {width: 50%}
   <div class="a"></div>              .a, .b { float: right }
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Semantically, I should see `[  [A][B]]` on my page, but it shows up as
`[  [B][A]]`

I get that I can just reorder my HTML and put B first if I want to see A first, but that's not really semantically correct. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Since your [A] is before [B]. it's floating right before too. You could use display flex, or display inline-block.

Comment: chances are you also want `.a,.b` to have a width of 50%

Comment: Yes but for simplicity's sake, I left those out for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox and `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">               
   <div class="a">a</div>
   <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Or set the child divs to `display: inline-block;` and use `text-align` on the container to align to the right.

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">               
   <div class="a">a</div><div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

And another solution would be to introduce a new element to wrap the child elements, float the new element right, then float the children left.

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
  float: right;
}
.inner > div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the flex answer worked. The inline-block didn't though since the divs are more complex and have borders and paddings

Comment: @penu awesome, you're welcome. you can use borders and paddings on inline-block elements btw.

Comment: awesome! I like your updated solution the best, works perfectly

Comment: @penu sweet! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container div {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to just wrap the child elements in a tag, and float it right :), but this is subject to adding a wrapping element, and converting your child div tags into inline blocks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 30%;
        }

        .c {
            float: right;
        }

        .a, .b {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left:20px;">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="c">
                <div class="a">a</div>
                <div class="b">b</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Floating your elements right will order them with the last div first. Try floating them both left.

```
.a, .b
{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: This would show `[[A][B]   ]` not `[   [A][B]]` which is what I want

Comment: @penu are you planning to fill the extra space? like `[[A][B]]`

Comment: If you want to float the [A][B] to the right of the container div.... try `container{float:right;]`

Comment: nah, not what i want